# SQL query to show results + or - 30mins than what is stored in table Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm new to `Python` and using `MySqldb` and in need of a bit of help. I have the below code in a python script to search a table in my database to find any ids of meetings that have today's date. Currently this works fine. However in my database the 'starttime' field has `yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss` , what I would like to do is not just pull up all the meeting id's that have todays date, but only if they have todays and starttime is + or - 30mins to that which is stored in the table. Is this possible? Thanks for any help in advance

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM meeting WHERE DATE(starttime) = DATE(NOW()) AND id=%s", (meetingid,))
if cur.rowcount:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    id 
FROM 
    meeting 
WHERE 
    starttime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
AND starttime <= NOW() + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
AND id=%s
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked a treat. Very great full for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the condition you can use on starttime:

```
starttime BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE AND NOW() + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
```

Comment: Be careful using `BETWEEN` with dates. The results aren't always what you'd expect.